# Código a correr em background em Google App Engine

Tags: java, thread, google-app-engine

Estou a fazer um "site" em GAE versão Java para servir de notificador quando uma fonte com resultados que estou à espera fique online. É suposto verificar o link em causa cada 24 horas. Já tenho tudo a funcionar, mas como é normal, o site fica a "carregar" até que passe o limite do tempo de espera que eu defini (para efeitos de teste, defini 10 segundos). Ora se o site tiver de ficar a carregar durante 24 horas até chegar a altura dele verificar o site novamente, o browser vai-me dar *timeout* ou então tenho de ter um computador ligado a carregar o website, o que vai contra o objectivo todo!

É possível fazer o programa correr em *background* lá nos servidores da GAE se eu pôr um *thread* a processar?

Tenho o seguinte código a funcionar:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

       connection();

       timer();

      System.out.println("shit");
}

private void timer() throws IOException{

  if((lastcheckedDate + (10000)) > System.currentTimeMillis())
  {
      waiting();
  }
}

private void check () throws IOException{

                connection();
              if (code==200)
              {
                  sendMessage();
              }
              else if (code==404){
                     System.out.println("Still not available");
                     timer();
              }
}

private void waiting() throws IOException{
      while((lastcheckedDate  + (10000)) > System.currentTimeMillis())
      {

      }
      check();
}

private void sendMessage() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
System.out.println("Sending email notification");
  Properties props = new Properties();
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
  String msgBody = "The Vulcanus in Japan Shortlist seems to be available. Check the following link: " +
        URL;
  try {
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("x@gmail.com", "Notifier"));
      msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("x@gmail.com", "ipunna"));
      msg.setSubject("Change in x link");
      msg.setText(msgBody);
      Transport.send(msg);
  }catch (AddressException e) {
      System.out.println("Address Exception occured");
  }catch (MessagingException e){
      System.out.println("Messaging Exception occured");
  }
}

private void connection() throws IOException{
     URL vjselec = new URL(URL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)selec.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.connect();

      code = connection.getResponseCode();


       lastcheckedDate = connection.getDate(); 
       System.out.println("first Date: " +  lastcheckedDate);
       connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Você já viu como funcionam as [TasksQueues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) no GAE? Acho que pode te ajudar, apesar de não ter entendido muito bem o que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 1):

O **Task Queue Java API** vai ajudar no que você precisa:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/

Coloquei alguns exemplo para você entender como funciona...

Tarefas dentro de transações:

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
try {
    Transaction txn = ds.beginTransaction();

    // ...

    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/path/to/my/worker"));

    // ...
    txn.commit();
} catch (DatastoreFailureException e) {
}
```

Eliminar tarefas:

```
// Purge entire queue...
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("foo");
queue.purge();

// Delete an individual task...
Queue q = QueueFactory.getQueue("queue1");
q.deleteTask("foo")
```

Comment: Resolvido! Para o que queria nem foi preciso criar tasks. Usei Push Queues que, no intervalo de tempo que defini, repetissem o acesso ao URL onde tenho o código essencial para execução até ele devolver o estado de 200 de HTTP. Simplificou muito mais o meu código, sem necessidade de ter aqueles loops de _while_ que tinha antes.